# jZebra applet testing without printer

Tags: javascript, pdf, applet, zebra-printers

Im trying to print a datamatrix with jZebra applet but my printer does not work with ZPL. Is there a way to test this without printer (to_PDF)? 
My concern is the commands that im sending.

Answer (score 3):

I'm tres, the developer of jzebra. Jzebra is primarily used for printers that accept generic text or raw print language commands.  Since jzebra only sends your commands to the printer it usually won't be able to generate a preview as that is printer specific.

As for a zpl printer emulator I've looked all over but unable to find one.

If you would like to know if jzebra will work for your printer, please post to jzebra-users@googlegroups.com!

-tres

Comment: Thanks Tres, The printer that was available for me did not work with jzebra, but once my code was online, the client tested it with their printer and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This service can help you preview your label before printing:

http://labelary.com/viewer.html

If you are ok with raw `^XA...` text output, the `FILE:` printer port combined with a `Generic / Text Only` driver on Windows is a great option on Windows XP, 8 and 10 (Win 7's `FILE:` port doesn't work well with Java)